# GitLab CI: how to build and then cache dependencies, then build them again when something changes in them?

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Let's say I have a C++ project, which depends on an external package, which is fetched (by using a given git tag or source path) from the web as the first stage, then its artifact is passed to the job which builds my project.

I would like to speed up the build by caching the build of the dependency package somehow.

Ideally, I would like to build that external package once, then cache it for the subsequent pipelines without re-build it at the start of a new pipeline.

Then, if the git tag or the source path I use to fetch the external package changes (which would be the sign that I'm using a different version of the external package), then the package is built again and the cache replaced with the new version.

I'm trying to get this use-case from various pieces of GitLab CI documentation but I cannot find the right answer.

Comment: Create a docker image with the package. Rebuild the docker image on git tag. Use this docker image for your workers.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk! I never used that but it sounds like a great suggestion. By chance, could you point me to a piece of documentation for that? Thanks a lot for your help! +1!

Answer (score 0):

Does the template not work? link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml

```
...
# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

# Pip's cache doesn't store the python packages
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching
#
# If you want to also cache the installed packages, you have to install
# them in a virtualenv and cache it as well.
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your message; maybe I'm missing something but, in your example, how do you trigger the build again when something changes? Ideally, I would like to recompile the cached package if I change the version of it I use for the build of my project. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think it does that automatically. :) like a normal pip local cache.